# How to add menu item to the debug pop-up context menu of Visual Studio? Visual Studio Extension

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I'm trying to make Visual Studio extension.
I want to add context menu item for the debug pop-up context menu.

[image: screenshot]

So if summarize I have next questions:

1. Could I define where my command should be and is it possible to add it to debug pop-up context menu?
2. Could I pass object on which context menu was opened as parameter?

I tried to create Command. But by default it will be located in tools tab.

Comment: Is this what you want? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/how-to-use-rule-based-ui-context-for-visual-studio-extensions?view=vs-2022